# Getting lists from Sharepoint vi CSOM is really slow

Tags: development, csom

I'm doing a simple web api-app in C# that uses SharePoint(Online) lists as a data backend. Every call to ClientContext.Web.GetListByTitle is really slow(about 2-3 seconds). The api fetches data from multiple lists so the api takes a long time to respond for every request.

This code is runs really slow:

```
List list = clientContext.Web.GetListByTitle(listName);
```

listName is a string.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: are you really using `Web.GetListByTitle`? Or did you mean `Web.Lists.GetByTitle()` ?

Comment: I was. Tried Web.Lists.GetByTitle() and it seems faster! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short:** If you make multiple requests try to "batch" them - you can load multiple things before calling `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery`. The main problem - mostly - is not the query you send to SharePoint but the time it takes to contact the server (i.e. establishing the connection to the service-endpoint).

**Long:**
Fundamentally, you can get a list by either calling [`Web.Lists.GetByTitle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.getbytitle.aspx) or [`Web.Lists.GetById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.getbyid.aspx).

For data access csom uses the endpoint `/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery` which get's the "query" in xml. From looking at the xml you'll see which internal (SSOM) methods are called in SharePoint.

For a simple `GetByTitle` the xml looks like this:

```
<Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009">
    <Actions>
        <ObjectPath Id="2" ObjectPathId="1" />
        <ObjectPath Id="4" ObjectPathId="3" />
        <ObjectPath Id="6" ObjectPathId="5" />
        <ObjectPath Id="8" ObjectPathId="7" />
        <ObjectIdentityQuery Id="9" ObjectPathId="7" />
        <Query Id="10" ObjectPathId="7">
            <Query SelectAllProperties="true">
                <Properties />
            </Query>
        </Query>
    </Actions>
    <ObjectPaths>
        <StaticProperty Id="1" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" />
        <Property Id="3" ParentId="1" Name="Web" />
        <Property Id="5" ParentId="3" Name="Lists" />
        <Method Id="7" ParentId="5" Name="GetByTitle">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Type="String">Documents</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Method>
    </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

For a `GetById` the xml looks like this:

```
<Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009">
    <Actions>
        <ObjectPath Id="2" ObjectPathId="1" />
        <ObjectPath Id="4" ObjectPathId="3" />
        <ObjectPath Id="6" ObjectPathId="5" />
        <ObjectPath Id="8" ObjectPathId="7" />
        <Query Id="9" ObjectPathId="7">
            <Query SelectAllProperties="true">
                <Properties />
            </Query>
        </Query>
    </Actions>
    <ObjectPaths>
        <StaticProperty Id="1" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" />
        <Property Id="3" ParentId="1" Name="Web" />
        <Property Id="5" ParentId="3" Name="Lists" />
        <Method Id="7" ParentId="5" Name="GetById">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Type="Guid">{8080c958-bdc6-4a25-88ce-b47b97b044ff}</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Method>
    </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

The main difference is the `<Method Id="7"` which calls either `SPList.GetById` or `SPList.GetByTitle` - the difference from looking at the code is that `SPList.GetByTitle` is exactly one call to get the list in question, whereas `SPList.GetByTitle` enumerates all lists until it finds the corresponding.

So yes - there is a better way: Use `Web.Lists.GetById` - but if you don't have thousands and thousands of lists it will not make a noticeable difference.